# "Sudo" fails with "sudo requires a tty" when executed from PuTTY command line

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, tty

I'm trying to run some commands on a remote CentOS machine using PuTTY. I'm using the following command:

```
putty.exe -ssh [IP] -l [user] -pw [password] -m [Script]
```

Where `[Script]` is a .txt file containing the commands I want to run. The issue is that one of the commands requires `sudo`, and when PuTTY tries to run it I get an error:

> sudo requires a tty

The thing that's confusing me is that if I start the session without giving a script, then run the commands from the script manually, it works fine. I've tried using `-load` instead of `-ssh`, and it made no difference.

I can't change the `requiretty` setting in my `sudoers` file for security reasons, which is the only solution I've been able to find. Is there another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sudo` requires TTY/interactive session.

On the contrary the PuTTY/Plink `-m` switch uses non-interactive session by default.

Use the [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to override that.

```
putty.exe -ssh [IP] -l [user] -pw [password] -t -m [Script]
```

Comment: I didn't realize the the -m option did that. Adding -t fixed the sudo error. It's still not working, but I think the new issue is due to the script I'm trying to run, not PuTTY. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read the error: `sudo requires a tty`. That is, an interactive shell. You have to find an other way of doing those privileged instructions. For example, you *could* login as root **with a key-based authentication**.

Comment: This is supposed to be used for test automation, so using an interactive shell won't work. I'll look into key-based authentication.

Comment: technically you could login with a password, but this is a very bad idea security-wise. Maybe the real question here is *why do you need root access*? If for communicating with some devices, udev rules should be enough.