# Executing "su" with PuTTY Plink from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

I'm having trouble trying to get my batch file to also give me super user access in PuTTY/Plink. I can auto-input the ip and password but I want to also automate it to where it will also give me `su` access when I run this batch file. So far it runs up to the point where I need to manually enter `su` but I'm trying to automate that so I tried `-m commands.txt` and now it just crashes.. Looking for any help here thanks.

this is what I have so far

```
@echo off
color b
cls
echo What is the IP for the unit?:
set /p IP= :

echo What is the SSH Password for this unit?:
set /p Passw0rd= :

echo What is the Root Password for this unit?:
set /p ro0t= :

start plink.exe -ssh user@%IP% -pw %Passw0rd% -m commands.txt

exit/b
```

what in the `commands.txt`:

```
su
```

Answer (score 2):

The `su` gives you a hint what's wrong, for sure. But you cannot see it because you start `plink` using `start` in a new console window that immediately disappears. Remove the `start`, at least when debugging the problem.

Anyway, you most likely get *"standard in must be a tty"* or a similar message. The `su` by default needs terminal for the password prompt. The Plink is meant an for an automation, not an interactive use. So it by default does not allocate a pseudo terminal for the session. To force use of the terminal, add [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty):

```
plink.exe -t -ssh user@%IP% -pw %Passw0rd% -m commands.txt
```

---

A similar question: ["Sudo" fails with "sudo requires a tty" when executed from PuTTY command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39624073/850848)

---

As a next step, you will probably want to execute further commands *within* `su`. For that see [Executing (sudo) subcommands using Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432962/850848).

---

Though note that in general automating `su`, particularly `su` with a password, is usually a bad idea: [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).